# How can I implement my logic properly to populate my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Sorry guys, this problem I am running into is pretty trivial. I just can't wrap my head around it so hope someone can help me. Your help is really appreciated. I am getting JSON data through NSURLConnectDelegate with a web API. I get something like this back:

```
(
{
 id = 340
 name = Vicent },
{
 id = 339
 name = Johny },
{
 id = 338
 name = Eric }
)
```

and I save it in a NSMutableArray as a global variable. Now, I have a NSSet of "ids". For example:

```
{
340, 339
}
```

In the *numberOfRowsInSection*, I return the set's count. I am trying to load only the ids in the NSSet from the array with the data saved from the webAPI, so I do something like this in *cellForRowIndexPath*:

```
 for (NSNumber *num in [set allObjects]) {
            NSString *newString = [[savedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
            NSString *new = [num stringValue];
            if ([new isEqual:newString]) {
           }}
```

How can I just populate the ids I want?

Comment: Why don't you store your ids in a `Dictionary` where the key is the ID and the values are the names? That way you keep all your pertinent info together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON makes it look like you have an array of dictionaries, which is a reasonable data structure to use as the data source for a table view.

It sounds like you're trying to filter your array to only include the items that are in your set. Is that right?

If so, you could write code that would create a new array containing the subset of your array elements who's ID is also in your set. There are at least a half-dozen ways to do that. One fairly simple approach would be to use the NSArray method `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`. You'd pass that method a block of code that would check each array element to see if it's id object was in your set.
That would give you an NSIndexSet with the indexes of the items in your array who's ID are in your set. Then you could use the NSArray method objectsAtIndexes to get an array of only the objects that are also in the set. Something like this (Assuming that your array of dictionaries is called savedArray and your set is called allObjects:

```
//get the indexes of items in the array savedArray who's id appears in the set allObjects
NSIndexSet *indexes = [savedArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: 
  ^(NSDictionary *obj,
  NSUInteger idx,
  BOOL *stop)
  {
    return [allObjects member: obj[@"id"]] != nil;
  }
];

//Now build an (immutable) array of just the objects who's ID are in the set
NSArray *subArray = [savedArray objectsAtIndexes: indexes];
```

The array subArray created above is immutable. If you need a mutable array you would need to make a mutable copy, which is a one-line change.

Disclaimer: I still struggle a little with block syntax, so the above might not be exactly correct, but it gives you the general idea.

Comment: LOL. The site name is particularly amusing, although rather NSFW. At the bottom it includes a cleaner, less amusing but more work-friendly link to the same content: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com. Blucking flocks indeed.